# Project with ServiceStack.Clients only is throwing "The free-quota limit on '20 ServiceStack.Text Types' exception"

Tags: servicestack

I have a project that tests every API operation endpoint in sequence. Currently the project references SS 4.0.40 and only contains refs to ServiceStack.Client, ServiceStack.Interfaces and ServiceStack.Text (Interfaces and Text are dependencies of Client).

Everytime I run my project (after about 20 types created) I get this CLIENT SIDE error stating:

*Test method SecMsg.Messaging.API.ServiceStack.WebHostTests.AttachmentsTests.SendMessage_Test threw exception: 
ServiceStack.LicenseException: The free-quota limit on '20 ServiceStack.Text Types' has been reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license or visit https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3 to revert back to the free ServiceStack v3.*

Though according to the license the client has free unrestricted use for consuming services. Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

My worry is that our customers who do not have a SS License key might see this issue if they configure their API clients the same way I do....

Thanks

Jordan

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that its because in my test app, I am using the **.Dump()** extension method to display the Request and Responses in the Output window(and this method lives in the SS.Text nuget).

I guess the Dump method is protected under license (which is too bad... i find it very useful). It would be helpful if the offending method (in this case Dump) was included in the license violation error response.